# React + Webpack What am I doing Wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to get a really simple react + webpack shell.

Everything seems to be bundling and compiling correctly, but when I run the app, no react is rendered.

My webpack config...

```
  module.exports = {
entry: [
  './src/index.js'
],
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use:
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {presets: ['react', 'es2015']}
            }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
output: {
  path: __dirname + '/dist',
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: "./src",
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true
} };
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React App Setup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And Index.js

```
   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import App from './components/App.jsx';

   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And App.js if you need it

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      console.log("made it here");
    return (
     <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

I probably am using some type of loader wrong, but why would I see "Hello Word" and my console log statements in bundle.js if its not loading???

Comment: Seeing the comment below - if you are looking for something v. lightweight you should check out Parcel

Comment: Oh actually you probably need the script tag _before_ the html node

Comment: Try moving `<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>` into the `<head>` section of the html document

Comment: Thanks that was the key, rather than head, I moved after body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here... load the bundle AFTER the body. :)

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell what you're doing wrong from what you've provided, but I would highly recommend installing and using create-react-app via npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app

To do this, you can enter the following into a command prompt/CLI:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

I've used it for every project i've ever made and have had no problems getting a "hello world" going in seconds. This will get you a hello-world app running at your default localhost in directory `\my-app`

Comment: I don't want all the heavy weight that comes with that. It's really not that good.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19881517)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @Davіd - i've adjusted accordingly.